# Sorting an array on more than one criterion

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object

I have this method to sort an array of objects by the variable id, there's name & GPA, too. How would you go about sorting the entire array of objects? Im only getting the id's sorted but the names when outputted are mixed. This is what I have thus far.

```
private Student[] st;
private int count;

public ProcessStudents() {
    st = new Student[5];
    count = 0;

    public void sortAscendingID() {
        for (int n = 0; n < count - 1; n++) {
            int min = st[n].getId();
            int index = n;
            for (int o = n + 1; o < count; o++) {
                if (st[o].getId() < min) {
                    min = st[o].getId();
                    index = o;
                }
            }
            if (st[n].getId() > min) {
                int p = st[n].getId();
                st[n].setId(min);
                st[index].setId(p);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were writing code for a production system rather than say homework or whatever I'd do this:

```
List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>(Arrays.asList(st)); 
Collections.sort(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Would implement Comparable and override its method:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
    // return -1, 0 or 1 depending on compared fields.
    // if(this.GetId()>((Student)arg0).GetId())
    // ...
    return 0;
}


... 

Collections.sort(collectionOfStudentObjects);
```